# Send notification on asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, push-notification, notifications

I use ASP.Net MVC 5 and kendo-ui in my project and i want to create a feature that enable me to send a notification to all users from server so can anyone tell me an architecture, pattern or technology should i use ?

or any recommendation for tutorial

Comment: [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want something like broadcast to available clients.
You can use SignalR.
Nice tutorial is available at [SignalR with asp.net mvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#set-up-the-client-code)

you can use [for more info about SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

you have google for more info on signalr.

I hope this helps.